# Ionic 3 Calendar, catch the date changed while selecting

Tags: angular, calendar, ionic3

I need to fire the date selected by an user for perform a research in a database.
but I need to catch the event while another date is selected in the calendar.

this is me HTML code:

```
<ion-calendar #calendar 
    [events]="currentEvents"
    (dateSelected)="onDateSelected($event)"
    (onCurrentDatechanged)="onCurrentDatechanged($event)"
    (onEventSelected)="onEventSelected($event)"
    (onTitleChanged)="onTitleChanged($event)"
    (onTimeSelected)="onTimeSelected($event)"
    step="30"
    lang="es">
</ion-calendar>
```

and the ts module code: (I tried a lot of ways to catch the event but couldn't do it)

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DatabaseProvider } from '../../providers/database/database';
/**
 * Generated class for the ConsultaPage page.
 *
 * See https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info on
 * Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-consulta',
  templateUrl: 'consulta.html',
})
export class ConsultaPage {
    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController, 
        public navParams: NavParams,
        private database: DatabaseProvider
    ) {
        this.currentEvents = [
        {
            year: 2018,
            month: 6,
            date: 25
        },
        {
            year: 2018,
            month: 6,
            date: 26
        },
        {
            year: 2018,
            month: 6,
            date: 11
        },
        {
            year: 2018,
            month: 6,
            date: 27
        },
        {
            year: 2018,
            month: 11,
            date: 26
        }
        ];
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {

    }

    GetAllUsers(){
        this.database.GetAllUsers().then((data: any) => {
            console.log(data);
            this.ListUser = data;
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
    }

    onDateSelected() {
        alert('asd');
    }

    onCurrentDatechanged($event){
        alert('onCurrentDatechanged');
    }

    onEventSelected($event){
        alert('onEventSelected');
    }

    onTitleChanged($event){
        alert('onTitleChanged');
    }

     onTimeSelected($event){
        alert('onTimeSelected');
    }

}
```

[image: calendar view]

when I select another date, nothing happens!

Comment: I've found the solution as this. Hope it helps in the future! (I think it is for Ionic 3 only)

    <ion-calendar #calendar 
  [events]="currentEvents"
  (onDaySelect)="onDaySelect($event)"
  step="30"
  lang="es">
 </ion-calendar>
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your "onCurrentDatechanged" is not working due to typo mistake in your Html code. You have written "onCurrentDatechanged" which is not correct. It should be "onCurrentDateChanged". Please find modified HTML code below:

```
<ion-calendar #calendar 
  [events]="currentEvents"
  (dateSelected)="onDateSelected($event)"
  (onCurrentDateChanged)="onCurrentDatechanged($event)"
  (onEventSelected)="onEventSelected($event)"
  (onTitleChanged)="onTitleChanged($event)"
  (onTimeSelected)="onTimeSelected($event)"
  step="30"
  lang="es">
</ion-calendar>
```